# How to hide Entity Framework entity properties from strongly typed views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am using Entity Framework in my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application and I want to know how to prevent or hide fields from my entity from being generated in my strongly typed view? Right now several primary key fields and timestamp fields are being generated on the view which I do not want.

I know setting the property to `internal` as opposed to `public` works but I am not sure of the total downstream effect this will have. I prefer to use data annotations on the properties but the ones I have tried prevent Controller scaffolding or make them as hidden fields. I prefer for them to remain public but just not be generated in the strongly typed view.

**EDIT:**

To generate a strongly typed View, add a new 'View' in Visual Studio and select the class in the dialog to which the view is modeled after. This in turn will create a view with all of the controls that are represented by properties on the class. For example a `LastName` field is created as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Comment: Please define "Generated in the strongly typed view" as this could mean various things.

Comment: Check out my 'Edit' notes please.

Comment: What?? You can absolutely create a strongly typed **View** (not talking about Controllers here just to be clear) from an Entity class. The View will contain all of the controls modeled as I exhibited above via auto-generated code.

Comment: Miss read something, sorry. Read my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Answer to the question**

Attribute

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

or

```
[Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]
```

before the unwanted properties will prevent de designer to generate scaffolding fields for those properties.

Comment: I tried `[Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]` and it still generated the fields. I read the MSDN documentation on this annotation and it *seems* correct, but it is still generating those fields in the view. See my comment on the other answer in regards to `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]`

Comment: Honestly I don't get it at this point. I am seeing some really screwy behavior with VS.NET 2010 and creating these strongly typed views. I am not sure if there is some caching or what. I always make sure to rebuild the solution prior to deleting and recreating the strongly typed view after modifying the annotations. I *think* `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` is working but sometimes the fields still get generated in the View and sometimes they don't (as I expect). I restarted VS.NET and the 1st View I created worked perfectly with the annotation.

Comment: Here seems to be the proper combination. 1. Add the annotation on the Property: `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` 2. Delete the currently generated View that is incorrect with too many fields. 3. Build the Solution 4. Add -> View, select 'Strongly typed' and select the class with the annotations. The fields with `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` should hopefully not appear.

Comment: Oh yes. Scaffolding updates on compilation. Every time you touch your model, you have to compile to keep your scaffolding in sync. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: The timestamp field has to be rendered manually in a hidden field: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TimeStampField), or else you don't have the desired concurrency check.

Answer (score 7):

To hide a property from the UI via Data Annotations, decorate the property with

```
 [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

and they will be ignored by the editor templates.

Comment: This is true but **only** works when the `DisplayForModel` or `EditorForModel` helpers are used. This annotation does not work with the Helpers that are auto-generated by strongly typed Views in VS.NET.

Comment: You are wrong. ScaffoldColumn attribute works for automatically generated strongly typed views, HOWEVER, since you are using the Entity Framework, you would have to add the attribute inside the model's designer code (which is really not recommended). Unfortunatly, the attribute will not work "Out of the box" without applying it directly on the entity. The answer is therefor "It has to be done manualy" unless you write your own ScaffoldColumn attribute, if it's even possible. (Unless theres a hidden checkbox somewhere in the designer that i've missed)

Comment: I do add the annotations directly to the generated entity designer code. I want to be clear I agree with all sentiment to use ViewModels, but this was a special case example I am trying to do. Thus why I am working directly with the entities.

Answer (score 4):

You should use separate ViewModel classes that only contain the properties you want.

Comment: Actually, yes I am using ViewModels in my projects. But I am actually trying something different out with the perfect "1 view to 1 entity" example and I still would like to know how to accomplish my original question directly.

Comment: I'm confused. If you're using a ViewModel that only has properties required for the specific view, what other properties are there?

Comment: Sorry, it should have read *yes I am using ViewModels in most of my projects* This project I am not as it is an example / test harness and does not use ViewModels. For this particular instance, ViewModels are a work-around more than a direct answer to my question anyway.

Comment: I find I need to use the ScaffoldColumn attribute in viewmodels and in views that I build on them starting with an empty view.