# ASP.NET Entity Framework Hide Model Property from View when Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I've created a model for my application.  It includes properties (database fields) I want to show and use, and one property I want created in the database but not be visible on the view that is generated during scaffolding.  I want it treated like the ID property is treated.

```
    [... OTHER CLASS PROPERTIES ABOVE ...]

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Job Number")]
    public string EntryJobNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Description")]
    public string EntryDescription { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name ="Date")]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
    [Range(0, 23.75)]
    [Display(Name ="Time Spent")]
    public decimal EntryHours { get; set; }

    public bool EntryExported { get; set; }  // I want this field in the database, but not visible in any of the CRUD views.
```

Is my only option to edit the views and remove the references to "EntryExported"?

SOLVED:  So adding

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

decoration to the model property took care of this.  Thanks to Davide Vitali for pointing me to the solution.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there must be attribute like [Browsable] or something similar, but I’m not 100% sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide Entity Framework entity properties from strongly typed views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952740/how-to-hide-entity-framework-entity-properties-from-strongly-typed-views)

Comment: The linked question held the answer Davide.  [ScaffoldColumn(false)] added to the model property make the scaffolding work as I wanted.